# How to avoid Duplicate Methods in yii2 (generated) ActiveRecord base models

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I'm getting duplicate methods when generating base models with ./yii helper/models

I know WHY this is happening, but I need a solution that holds similar data constraints while still properly generating the yii2 base models.

Sample data structure.

Alert(assignedTo, createdBy) -> Both fields are foreign keys of UserId

./yii helper/models will generate these methods in UserBase

```
public function getAlerts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\app\models\db\Alert::className(), ['assignedTo' => 'id']);
}

public function getAlerts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\app\models\db\Alert::className(), ['createdBy' => 'id']);
}
```

How can I fix this problem while only modifying the Database?

Comment: Can't you just rename the functions?

Comment: Thank you @Blizz.  Renaming the models would cause the next developer that runs the generator to have the same problem.  base models should never be modified directly.

Comment: If this is a problem regarding the model generation in Yii in general, you would probably be better of creating an issue on the github page itself?

Answer (score 0):

how about make sure which field has value?

```
public function getAlerts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\app\models\db\Alert::className(), [
        !empty($this->assignedTo) ? 'assignedTo' : 'createdBy' => 'id'
    ]);
}
```